# Remove pulseaudio.service on Debian Linux

Tags: debian, pulseaudio

In my journalctl log I get the following message:

```
pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
```

How do I remove `pulseaudio.service` while remaining on Gnome desktop? I have already moved `/usr/bin/pulseaudio`, and while that prevents the program from running, the error messages like the one above still keep polluting my `journalctl`.

Comment: Can you undo that moving; obviously, you're rendering the service broken. So, what you should to to get rid of the log message depends on what you want to achieve. What is the reason you want to "remove pulseaudio.service"? In  general, GNOME won't work without (unless you do something special), so there's no one "good universal solution" here.

Comment: I do not need any audio services in my system beyond alsa, and pulseaudio interferes with some of my MIDI functionality, hence why I would like to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian, Pulseaudio runs as a per-user systemd service.

So you could start disabling it with (using your regular user account; no `sudo` needed):

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

It is important to stop both the service itself and the socket; if the socket remains active, it will restart the service as soon as something attempts to use the socket.

If some other service still tries to activate `pulseaudio.service`, you can *mask* it to absolutely prevent it from running:

```
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio.service
```